# R: merge two data frames when either of two criteria matches

Tags: r, merge, data-manipulation

Say I have two dataframes like the following:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff") 
b = c(2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
#  n  s b
#1 2 aa 2
#2 3 bb 4
#3 5 cc 5  
#4 5 dd 4
#5 6 ee 3
#6 7 ff 2

n2 = c(5, 6, 7, 6) 
s2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "ll") 
b2 = c("hh", "nn", "ff", "dd")  
df2 = data.frame(n2, s2, b2)

 #   n2 s2 b2
 #1  5 aa hh
 #2  6 bb nn
 #3  7 cc ff
 #4  6 ll dd
```

I want to merge them to achieve the following result:

```
 #n s  b n2 s2 b2
 #2 aa 2 5  aa hh
 #3 bb 4 6  bb nn
 #5 cc 5 7  cc ff
 #5 dd 4 6  ll dd
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to merge the two dataframes whenever the values in s of the first data is found in either the s2 or the b2 columns of data2.

I know that merge can work when I specify the two columns from each dataframe but I am not sure how to ADD the OR condition in the merge function. Or how to achieve this goal using other commands from packages such as dpylr.

Also, to clarify, there will be a situation where s2 and b2 have matches with s column in the same row. If this is the case, then just merge them once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coupld of problems: 1) you have built a couple of dataframes with factors which has a tendency to screw up matching and indexing, so I used stringsAsFactors =FALSE in hte dataframe calls. 2) you have an ambiguous situation with no stated resolution when both s2 and b2 have matches in the s column (as does occur in your example):

```
> df2[c("s")] <- list( c( df$s[pmax( match( df2$s2 , df$s), match(df2$b2, df$s),na.rm=TRUE)]))
> df2
  n2 s2 b2  s
1  5 aa hh aa
2  6 bb nn bb
3  7 cc ff ff
4  6 ll dd dd
> df2[c("s")] <- list( c( df$s[pmin( match( df2$s2 , df$s), match(df2$b2, df$s),na.rm=TRUE)]))
> df2
  n2 s2 b2  s
1  5 aa hh aa
2  6 bb nn bb
3  7 cc ff cc
4  6 ll dd dd
```

Once you resolve the ambiguity to your satiusfaction just use the same method to extract and match the "b"s:

```
> df2[c("b")] <- list( c( df$b[pmin( match( df2$s2 , df$s), match(df2$b2, df$s),na.rm=TRUE)]))
> df2
  n2 s2 b2  s b
1  5 aa hh aa 2
2  6 bb nn bb 4
3  7 cc ff cc 5
4  6 ll dd dd 4
```

Modified df's:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(n = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7), s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", 
"dd", "ee", "ff"), b = c(2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2)), .Names = c("n", 
"s", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df2)
structure(list(n2 = c(5, 6, 7, 6), s2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "ll"
), b2 = c("hh", "nn", "ff", "dd"), s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"
), b = c(2, 4, 5, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("n2", 
"s2", "b2", "s", "b"), class = "data.frame")
```

One step solution:

```
> df2[c("s", "c")] <-  df[pmin( match( df2$s2 , df$s), match(df2$b2, df$s),na.rm=TRUE), c("s", "b")]
> df2
  n2 s2 b2  s c
1  5 aa hh aa 2
2  6 bb nn bb 4
3  7 cc ff cc 5
4  6 ll dd dd 4
```

Comment: It could work but both of the actual two data frames I have have above 30 columns. If I add one column at a time, it will take too long. Also, to clarify, there will not be a situation where s2 and b2 have matches with s column in the same row.

Comment: I'll post a compact for that does both columns in one step:

Comment: Thanks for revising the solutions. But what I mean is that in the actual data, each data has more than 30 columns together. And 2 columns are the "s" and "c" as the in the first dataframe. I want to use these columns as the selection criteria without losing other columns (the other 20+ columns) that I did not post up. Is that in this solution, it is effectively adding two more columns to df2, but what I really want is in addition to the two columns, the result of 20+ columns as well.

Comment: You comment does not explain your difficulties in language that allowsa me to understand where the problem lies. In particular I don't understand why you cannot "drag along" any other columns from the first `df` by adding their names to the `j`-argument of "[" in the version above.

Comment: do you mean if I want to add three columns s,c,a to df2, it will be df2[c("s", "c", "a")] ?

Comment: As long as you do that on both sides of the assignment, it seems to work in your example. The key is getting the row indexing correct. You can then bring across as many columns as you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with SQL you could use that:

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("SELECT l.*, r.*
              FROM df as l
              INNER JOIN df2 as r
              on l.s = r.s2 OR l.s = r.b2")

res
  n  s b n2 s2 b2
1 2 aa 2  5 aa hh
2 3 bb 4  6 bb nn
3 5 cc 5  7 cc ff
4 5 dd 4  6 ll dd
5 7 ff 2  7 cc ff
```

**Data**:

```
df<-structure(list(n = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7), s = structure(1:6, .Label = c("aa", 
"bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"), class = "factor"), b = c(2, 4, 
5, 4, 3, 2)), .Names = c("n", "s", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(n2 = c(5, 6, 7, 6), s2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("aa", 
"bb", "cc", "ll"), class = "factor"), b2 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("dd", "ff", "hh", "nn"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("n2", 
"s2", "b2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried but it says error in statement: no such table: df2, while df2 is stored in the working environment

Comment: I reran and it works for me. I posted the data I used as well (which should be the same as yours).

Comment: it still does not run on my own data while it works on the sample data I posted (I also just ran this). Is there any other way to merge the two?

Comment: How fast is this one compare to a normal merge?

Answer (score 2):

We could use a fuzzy join, it might not be very efficient in this case if you have big data but it's certainly readable. Using my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) which wraps (in this case) around *fuzzyjoin* :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
safe_inner_join(df, df2, ~ X("s") == Y("s2") | X("s") == Y("b2"))
#   n  s b n2 s2 b2
# 1 2 aa 2  5 aa hh
# 2 3 bb 4  6 bb nn
# 3 5 cc 5  7 cc ff
# 4 5 dd 4  6 ll dd
# 5 7 ff 2  7 cc ff
```

The *fuzzyjoin* syntax would be:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_inner_join(df, df2, match_fun = NULL, 
                 multi_by = list(x = "s", y= c("s2","b2")), 
                 multi_match_fun = function(x,y) x == y[,"s2"] | x == y[,"b2"])
#   n  s b n2 s2 b2
# 1 2 aa 2  5 aa hh
# 2 3 bb 4  6 bb nn
# 3 5 cc 5  7 cc ff
# 4 5 dd 4  6 ll dd
# 5 7 ff 2  7 cc ff
```

Answer (score 0):

One base approach is rbinding two merges. You need to re-create the corresponding join keys in `df2` to effectively concatenate the frames. Also, #5 row does not emerge in desired results:

```
t1 <- merge(df, df2, by.x=c("s"), by.y=c("s2"))
t1$s2 <- t1$s

t2 <- merge(df, df2, by.x=c("s"), by.y=c("b2"))
t2$b2 <- t2$s

finaldf <- rbind(t1, t2)

#    s n b n2 b2 s2
# 1 aa 2 2  5 hh aa
# 2 bb 3 4  6 nn bb
# 3 cc 5 5  7 ff cc
# 4 dd 5 4  6 dd ll
# 5 ff 7 2  7 ff cc
```