# Merging two tables by multiple conditions

Tags: r

I've been unable to find a previous question which answers exactly what I'm attempting.

df1

```
chr  position  effect.exposure  ...
1    12345     A                ...
2    54321     G                ... 
2    6789      C                ...
3    9876      D                ...
```

df2

```
chr  position  effect.outcome  other  ...
1    12345     A               C      ...
2    54321     T               G      ...
3    12314     C               A      ...
5    12321     C               D      ...
```

That is the general format of my data, with there being multiple other columns not relevant to the merging, but which need to be kept.

What I want is to merge rows that have the same "chr" and "position" strictly, but also make sure that "effect.exposure" in df1 matches either "effect.outcome" or "other" in df2. Importantly, if "effect.exposure" does not match either of "effect.outcome" or "other", I want that row to be dropped.

"chr" and "position" can be combined to have only one column for each in the outcome data, but I want the two "effect" and the "other" columns to remain separate in the final datatable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: merge two data frames when either of two criteria matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753092/r-merge-two-data-frames-when-either-of-two-criteria-matches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around the issue. The way I have done it is by merging the two dataframes by `chr` and `position`.

```
new.df <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("chr", "position"))
```

From here, i've then taken a subset of this dataframe where `effect.exposure` is equal to either `effect.outcome` or `other`.

```
final.df <- new.df[new.df$effect.exposure == new.df$effect.outcome |
                   new.df$effect.exposure == new.df$other, ]
```

Full disclosure, this may not be the most efficient method, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of one of the older answers, wherein 2 `merge`s are performed, then the results of each merge are `rbind`. The issue with your data is how to merge the results with different number of columns. You can use `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::spread` to deal with that.

Your data

```
df1 <- structure(list(chr = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), position = c(12345L, 
54321L, 6789L, 9876L), effect.exposure = c("A", "G", "C", "D"
), misc = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), .Names = c("chr", "position", 
"effect.exposure", "misc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(chr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), position = c(12345L, 
54321L, 12314L, 12321L), effect.outcome = c("A", "T", "C", "C"
), other = c("C", "G", "A", "D")), .Names = c("chr", "position", 
"effect.outcome", "other"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Extension of older answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result1 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("chr", "position", "effect.exposure" = "effect.outcome")) %>%
              gather(key, value, -chr, -position, -effect.exposure)

  # chr position effect.exposure   key value
# 1   1    12345               A  misc     a
# 2   1    12345               A other     C

result2 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("chr", "position", "effect.exposure" = "other")) %>%
            gather(key, value, -chr, -position, -effect.exposure)

  # chr position effect.exposure            key value
# 1   2    54321               G           misc     b
# 2   2    54321               G effect.outcome     T

ans <- rbind(result1, result2) %>%
            spread(key, value)

  # chr position effect.exposure effect.outcome misc other
# 1   1    12345               A           <NA>    a     C
# 2   2    54321               G              T    b  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
final_df <- df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by=c("chr", "position")) %>%
  mutate(Resp_final = if_else((as.character(effect_exposure)==as.character(effect_outcome)) | 
                                (as.character(effect_exposure)==as.character(other)), 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(Resp_final==1) %>%
  select(-Resp_final)
final_df
```

Output is:

```
  chr position effect_exposure col4 effect_outcome other col5
1   1    12345               A Asdf              A     C 1234
2   2    54321               G  Abc              T     G  987
```

```
#Sample data
> dput(df1)
structure(list(chr = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), position = c(12345L, 
54321L, 6789L, 9876L), effect_exposure = structure(c(1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D", "G"), class = "factor"), col4 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Abc", "Asdf", "qwerty", "xyz"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("chr", 
"position", "effect_exposure", "col4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(chr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), position = c(12345L, 
54321L, 12314L, 12321L), effect_outcome = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "T"), class = "factor"), other = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D", "G"), class = "factor"), 
    col5 = c(1234L, 987L, 675L, 3456L)), .Names = c("chr", "position", 
"effect_outcome", "other", "col5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```